# Lodash - deep type validation

Tags: node.js, validation, types, lodash

Is there a lodash method (or good approach in plain javascript) for validating a nested object against a schema definition.

For instance, given a schema-defining object:

```
{ 
  profile: {
    application: {
      dates:{
        startDate: String,
        endDate: String
      },
      status: String,
      jobs: [{
        type: Number,
        title: String
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to type validate this sample object against the definition:

```
{
  "profile": {
    "application": {
      "dates": {
        "startDate": "2011-09-20T15:00:00.000Z",
        "endDate": "2018-10-05T15:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "status": "PENDING",
      "jobs": [
        {
          "type": 5,
          "title": "Waiter"
        },
        {
          "type": 1,
          "title": "Engineer"
        },
        {
          "type": 33,
          "title": "Artist"
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: JOI will be a good option.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Node.js like your tags describe, you could use a schema validation library, there a few out there. One example would be [jsonschema](https://github.com/tdegrunt/jsonschema).

Simple example:

```
var Validator = require('jsonschema').Validator;
var v = new Validator();
var instance = 4;
var schema = {"type": "number"};
console.log(v.validate(instance, schema));
```